# Can I use Cursor in RecyclerView.Adapter for binding Cartesian product (two joined tables)?

Tags: android, sqlite, join, cursor

Maybe I didn't quite understand the purpose and possibilities of the `Cursor`. I am interested in the issue.

I have two tables, and one-to-many relationship

```
Content
------------------
id
article_id
index
type
text
images

Images
------------------
id 
content_id
content_index
image_index
url
title
```

So, I want see all content for article with id = 1.

```
SELECT * FROM content
WHERE article_id = 1
```

Result rows:

```
id    article_id    index  type     text           images 
-------------------------------------------------------------
1     1             0      "text"   "Text1"        NULL
2     1             1      "text"   "Text2"        NULL
3     1             2      "text"   "Text3"        NULL
```

Ok, next in my `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter` I get cursor for each row in result and bind it to `UI`:

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor) {    
             String type = cursor.getString(TYPE);
             String text = cursor.getString(TEXT);
             //......
    }
```

But if content has type "images", I can use JOIN for joined tables and get result **Cartesian product**, something like:

```
   id    article_id    index  type       text       url            title
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     1             0      "text"     "Text1"    NULL           NULL  
   2     1             1      "text"     "Text2"    NULL           NULL
   3     1             2      "images"   NULL       "image1.png"   "img1"
   3     1             2      "images"   NULL       "image2.png"   "img2"
   3     1             2      "images"   NULL       "image3.png"   "img3"
   4     1             3      "text"     "Text3"    NULL           NULL
```

In this case how use cursor in

```
onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, Cursor cursor);
```

There are typical solutions for this issue? I was looking for a solution to the StackOverflow, but with no results, I begin to doubt that in such cases, you can use the `Cursor`?

**UPDATE**

If use `GROUP BY index` I don't see all images for content row:

```
   id    article_id    index  type       text       url            title
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------
   1     1             0      "text"     "Text1"    NULL           NULL  
   2     1             1      "text"     "Text2"    NULL           NULL
   3     1             2      "images"   NULL       "image1.png"   "img1"
   4     1             3      "text"     "Text3"    NULL           NULL
```

Comment: I do not understand what your question is. You do not want to show the duplicate values for article_id?

Comment: You're right, I do not know where I must to group data. I don't want to show duplicate rows for index.

Comment: You need to use group by to limit the result: Select xx,xx,xx,xx from content where xxx group by xxx,xx,xx

Comment: I update post, did you mean this?

Comment: So what exactly do you want to show? Only articles that have a url value, or all url values even if they are null, or ...?

Comment: I want show all content, if content has type "text" then it doesn't has images and show only text. If content has type "images" then I want show all images for this row from Images table.